# Design patterns for Hibernate entity fields that are derived - Mutability Concerns

Tags: java, hibernate, immutability

I am currently working on a code where the entity loaded from DB needs multiple updates based on the use case. I am striving to prevent mutable objects in my code. Given how hibernate works, I see that I have no choice but to allow entities as mutable so as to invoke setters to update the entity.

Is there a way around this ?

Comment: No. An entity is inherently mutable, and one of the main points is that changes made to the entities are transparently made persistent to the database. Note that entities are not supposed to be shared between threads, and each session will have its own entity instances.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet .. The code is not sharing any entities between threads, it was more from a development standpoint that I was trying to see if immutable objects could be used through out the project. I think I can achieve that goal for almost every other use case except entities..